# Cannot open TIF file from GMail on Android device

Tags: gmail, images

Android: 4.1.2

When I try to open a TIF file from an email in GMail, I get the following message: `Couldn't load image`

Is there a plug-in or a solution to fix this? I don't want to use a 3rd-party application.

Comment: There is no solution because android hasn't support of tif format. So you need to use 3rd party software. And I think that preview that you see in gmail app is generated on server side of gmail